# Powerpoint VBA - adjust positions of chart and axis titles

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have the following code:

```
Sub StandardiseChart(ByVal control As IRibbonControl)

Dim activeShape As Shape

'Determine Which Shape is Active
If ActiveWindow.Selection.Type = ppSelectionShapes Then
'Loop in case multiples shapes selected
    Dim shp As Shape
    For Each shp In ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange
         Set activeShape = shp ' First shape selected
         Exit For
    Next

'Now, reformat the selected shape if it is a chart
    With activeShape
        If .HasChart Then

            ' Chart title
            .Chart.HasTitle = True
            With .Chart.ChartTitle
                .Left = 0
                .Top = 0
            End With

            ' Y axis
            With .Chart.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary)
            .HasTitle = True
            .AxisTitle.Text = "Placeholder"
            .AxisTitle.Left = 0
            .AxisTitle.Top = 20
            .AxisTitle.Orientation = 0
            End With

            ' Plot Area
            With .Chart.PlotArea
                .Left = 10
                .Top = 50
            End With

        End If

    End With ' activeShape

End If

End Sub
```

What I'd like it to do is 3 things:

1. Pin the Chart Title to the top left corner of the entire object (this seems fine)
2. Set the y-axis title so that there is 20pt of space between it and the chart title (also seems fine)
3. Create a further 50pt of space between the plot area and the y-axis title (not fine).

No matter what I do (I've tried adjusting the number to 70 rather than 50, and even bigger), I can't seem to adjust the space to achieve (3). Specifically, the plot area doesn't move no matter what I do.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add a dot to the end of Chart.Plotarea, you can see the list of methods. In your case, you're looking for **.InsideLeft** and **.InsideTop**, since you want to adjust the inside distance from the chart area:

```
With .Chart.PlotArea
    .InsideLeft = 70
    .InsideTop = 70
End With
```